# get latitude longitude based on address api

Tags: php, api, geolocation

I am using http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/ api from google to get geolocation based on address.
I put an address like this :"1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA", and getting the needed results, and I just need from here latitude and longitude.
It works well from my localhost, but then I try to use it from hosting's server it says request denied.
So my question is: if is there a similat api where i can send postcode street and house number and get latitude and longitude, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your webhost might not allow such connections to other servers. Contact them to make sure they do. But that kind of problems often show up when you open socket connections, which i guess is not necessary for this API.

Otherwise you can try Yahoo's Geocoding API: http://developer.yahoo.com/maps/rest/V1/geocode.html
Or as Yahoo themselfes suggest, the new PlaceFinder API. A link to PlaceFinder can be found at the same link.

If you're not satisfied with Yahoo, there is a similar API at multimap.com.

Comment: I found the problem with google it was my fault, but still they offer 2500 requests per day so it could be not enough, so your suggestions could be very handy. Thanks